# Use p6spy to log Spark JDBC datasource

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, p6spy

I would like to log the JDBC statements that my Spark job executes with the help of [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy).

Using p6spy is usually straightforward: one inserts the string `:p6spy:` into the jdbc url and includes the p6spy driver classes into the classpath of the application. After that, all jdbc actions will be logged into a file.

For example if the original (MySQL) connection string was

```
jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/spark_test
```

the connection string with logging enabled would be

```
jdbc:p6spy:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/spark_test
```

I use this line to write a dataframe into a MySQL table

```scala
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc("jdbc:p6spy:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/spark_test", "test_table", prop)
```

with `prop` containg the db user and password.

This line of code fails with the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"value" INTEGER NOT NULL)' at line 1
```

Without the `:p6spy:` part in the connection string everything works as expected.

---

### My findings so far

The reason for the error is that Spark tries to execute the statement

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table ("value" INTEGER NOT NULL)
```

which includes **"** around the column name. The correct character would be **`** for MySQL.

Spark can handle different SQL dialects. The dialects are implemented in the package [org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc). The dialect to use is chosen depending on the jdbc url of the database. Each dialect object implements the method `canHandle(url : String)`. The [MySQLDialect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/MySQLDialect.scala) handles urls starting with `jdbc:mysql` but not those starting with `jdbc:p6spy:mysql`. Unfortunately Spark defaults to the [NoopDialect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1d1a2079a56de25b0d14dd57f458a0f3830a6e14/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala#L248) for an unknown url type. This dialect adds the **"** around the column name.

---

### Possible solution

It is possible to register new database dialects by calling [JdbcDialects.registerDialect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1d1a2079a56de25b0d14dd57f458a0f3830a6e14/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala#L209). Here one could register a new dialect that implements the `canHandle` method as

```scala
override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:p6spy:mysql")
```

and then delegates all other method calls to the orginal MySQL dialect.

Unfortunately the MySQLDialect object is declared as

```scala
private case object MySQLDialect extends JdbcDialect {
  ...
}
```

so my own implementation of a dialect cannot use MySQLDialect directly. An option would be to copy the code of MySQLDialect into my own dialect object (the code is not long), but I would like to avoid copying code.

Are there any other options?

I am using Spark 2.4.5